# How to call a function when something is done

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, mongodb, express

I am trying to make it so when the query is done, and the `data` array is full, it should then do the `res.send()` part.

This code is currently failing -- the sendData function runs before the query is done:

```
function showPostsOnPage(pageNumber, nPerPage) {
  funnyPosts.find().skip((pageNumber-1)*nPerPage).limit(nPerPage).each( function(err, post) {
    data.push(post);
  });
  sendData(data);
}

function sendData(data) {
  res.send(
    { msg: '', data: data } // Alerts empty on the client side.
  );    
}
```

On the client side I use:

```
var pageNumber = {
  'pageNumber': 30
};

$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  data: pageNumber,
  url: '/nextHomeImages'
}).done(function( response ) {
  if (response.msg === '') {
    alert(response.data);
  } else {
    console.log('Error: ' + response.msg);
  }
});
```

Comment: `.each` being carried out shows that there is a length.   Why dont you have a counter --, and then `if (counter ==0)sendData(data);`

Comment: np, lemme know if it works. :)  ill submit it as an answer

Comment: Working, I did `if (data.length === 3)` `sendData(data);`

Comment: Are you sure `.each( function(err, post) {
    data.push(post);
  });` isn't async which means there's no way u send the data before the `data` array is populated

Comment: It is async, the sendData function was being triggered before data was done being populated. So now after each time data is pushed to `data`, I check if the length is `nPerPage`and if it is I trigger the sendData function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I noticed keyword `each` which to me jumped as jQuery.

With that said there is a finite length.  I would do something like:

```
var len;
function showPostsOnPage(pageNumber, nPerPage) {
  var _posts = funnyPosts.find().skip((pageNumber-1)*nPerPage).limit(nPerPage);
  len = _posts.length;
  _posts.each( function(err, post) {
    data.push(post);
    len --;
    if (len <= 0) sendData(data);
  });
  //sendData(data);
}

function sendData(data) {
  res.send(
    { msg: '', data: data } // Alerts empty on the client side.
  );    
}
```

Comment: There is something wrong when doing var _posts = funnPosts...
When console logging _posts, it returns params like `{ _construct_args: [],` instead of the actual posts

Comment: Must be a mongoskin issue.